# Bootstrap glyphicon: 100% width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, glyphicons

In my webapp I have a glyphicon contained in a div within a grid.

I'd like like the glyphicon to be full width and proportional height (to be displayed correctly).

How can I do ?

Plunker is: http://plnkr.co/edit/9GL54M1ozwwpQgJXlCbc?p=preview

HTML is:

```
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" style="border: solid 2px red">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS is:

```
.glyphicon {
  width: 100%;
  color: green;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: glyphicons are like characters... you should try to set font-size to set icon size... but tryin to put it with 100% width will be kinda tricky...

Comment: only "real way" to do the job, without use of media queries and font-size would be to use your glyphicon as an image... / img-responsive...

Comment: you could experiment with `font-size:25vw` changing the number so that the font is the same proportion of viewport width as it's containing element. Assuming that the element is always the same proportion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this.. to make the glyphicon **Star** icon responsive.
You could do it this way.
Use this to do what you are wanting to achieve here.
Not so much to fill the width but to size to what you need it to do.
Hope this helps.

```
.star-size {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    color:orangered;
}
```

But please read **[this info](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)**.

[image: responsive glyphicon]

If you also want the height of the div block to be reponsive with the star icon, then change the `.inner-block` class to this...

```
.inner-block {
    padding-top: 15px; 
    padding-bottom: 15px; 
    background-color:black;  
}
```

And then it will act like this.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>HTML/CSS Block not appearing</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<style>
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.spacer {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}    
.block {
    height: 240px;
    padding-top: 15px;  
    background-color:orangered;  
}
.inner-block {
    height: 120px;
    padding-top: 15px;  
    background-color:black;  
}     
  
.star-size {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    color:orangered;
}     
.center-div {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
        
}       
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


    
<div class="container col-lg-12 spacer"></div>
        
  <div class="container block">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4 text-center inner-block center-div" >
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star-size"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>  

    

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicons are actually characters in a special font so they don't really scale like that. If you really want to do it you should create an image and stretch that with `width: 100%` for example.

Another possible (but nasty) solution would be to use CSS transformations, but it's a hack, doesn't automatically scale and requires some extra hacks to position correctly:

```
.glyphicon:before {
  margin-left: 120px;
  display:inline-block;
  transform:scale(17,1);
  -webkit-transform:scale(17,1);
  -moz-transform:scale(17,1)
  -ms-transform:scale(17,1);
  -o-transform:scale(17,1); 
}
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xk19bLqZKj7sDulZ6AiH?p=preview